# Error while building hadoop application using maven

Tags: java, hadoop, maven-3, hdfs

I have following program , I am building with maven , the POM file i have given just below the program. While building , i am getting errors given below pom file . I am new to hadoop and maven as well. I can not  know if i am building the program with correct artifact(hadoop-common) . The program is for hadoop-2.2.0. Please put some light on this.

```
package com.example.hdfs;

//cc URLCat Displays files from a Hadoop filesystem on standard output using a        URLStreamHandler
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;

//vv URLCat
public class URLCat {

static {
    URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new URL(args[0]).openStream();
        IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeStream(in);

    }
}
```

}

pom.xml

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>hdfsTrying</groupId>
<artifactId>hdfstrying</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>hdfstrying</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>hdfsTrying.hdfstrying.URLCat</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### Errors

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-math/2.1/commons-math-2.1.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.4/avro-1.7.4.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.5/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.4/avro-1.7.4.jar (297 KB at 1.7 KB/sec)
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, could not read expected checksum: java.net.ConnectException: null to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.jar.sha1 for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.jar
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, could not read expected checksum: java.net.ConnectException: null to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.4/avro-1.7.4.jar.sha1 for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.4/avro-1.7.4.jar
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, could not read expected checksum: java.net.ConnectException: null to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-math/2.1/commons-math-2.1.jar.sha1 for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-math/2.1/commons-math-2.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4:56.462s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Nov 30 10:39:37 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/97M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hdfstrying: Could not resolve dependencies for project hdfsTrying:hdfstrying:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3, com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0, org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5, org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1: Could not transfer artifact com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): null to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar: UnresolvedAddressException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project hdfstrying: Could not resolve dependencies for project hdfsTrying:hdfstrying:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3, com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0, org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5, org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1: Could not transfer artifact com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): null to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project hdfsTrying:hdfstrying:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3, com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0, org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5, org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1: Could not transfer artifact com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): null to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:165)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3, com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0, org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5, org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1: Could not transfer artifact com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): null to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:541)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:220)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifacts(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:331)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:434)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:150)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): null to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$3.wrap(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:1426)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$3.wrap(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:1417)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:908)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:902)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector.get(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:279)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:460)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: null to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:83)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.doConnect(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:857)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:731)
    at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:484)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$GetTask$1.onThrowable(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:532)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponseFuture.abort(NettyResponseFuture.java:287)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:87)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.doConnect(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:857)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:731)
    at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:484)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$GetTask$1.onThrowable(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:532)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponseFuture.abort(NettyResponseFuture.java:287)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.abort(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1301)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.doConnect(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:853)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:731)
    at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:484)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$GetTask$1.onThrowable(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:532)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponseFuture.abort(NettyResponseFuture.java:287)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.abort(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1301)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.doConnect(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:853)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:731)
    at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:484)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:771)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector.get(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:270)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:89)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:510)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:140)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:103)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:60)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.handleDownstream(HttpClientCodec.java:82)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleDownstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:114)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:541)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:218)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:227)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:188)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.doConnect(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:836)
    ... 50 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any proxy? if so, add proxy details in your `settings.xml` file in `apache-maven-3.*.*/conf` directory. It will be something like this in `settings.xml` file. Uncomment and add your proxy details.

```
<proxies>
  <!-- proxy
   | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
   |
  <proxy>
    <id>optional</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <username>proxyuser</username>
    <password>proxypass</password>
    <host>proxy.host.net</host>
    <port>80</port>
    <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>
-->
</proxies>
```